# TypeScript how to trigger action in a component from the another one

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use Ant Design and with a click from 'antd' button I want to trigger changing step in custom 'antd' step component. How do I do this? Thank you! (https://ant.design/components/button/) + (https://ant.design/components/steps/)

```
const StepOne = ({ onClick }: any) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Button type='primary' onClick={onClick}>
                    StepOneLogIn
                  </Button>
                  <Button>StepOneRegister</Button>
                </div>
              );
            };
export const Order = () => {
          const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);

          //Final
          return (
            <div>
              <Steps size='small' current={currentStep}>
                <Step title='text' />
                <Step title='text' />
                <Step title='text' />
                <Step title='text' />
              </Steps>

              <Divider />
              <div>
                {currentStep === 0 ? (
                  <StepOne onClick={setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div>{currentStep === 1 ? <StepTwo /> : null}</div>
              <div>{currentStep === 2 ? <StepThree /> : null}</div>
              <div>{currentStep === 3 ? <StepFour /> : null}</div>
            </div>
          );
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally passing the return value of `setCurrentStep` rather than a function to the `onClick` handler. You should change

`<StepOne onClick={setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />`

to this

`<StepOne onClick={() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)} />`

`() => setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1)` creates a function, which will call your `setCurrentStep` function, and passes that function to the `onClick` prop, whereas your earlier code was directly calling `setCurrentStep` and passing the return value of that to the `onClick` prop, causing nothing to happen when the button is pressed.

Other than that, the rest of your code looks right for trying to trigger the action from your child `StepOne` component

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, I fixed the problem with your help that way!

Comment: @NikolaiMelnikov no problem